# Exception of type 'ExcelDna.Integration.XlCallException' was thrown while reading cell values from excelreference

Tags: c#, excel-dna

Getting this exception while reading value from whole selected sheet.

Selected a whole current sheet.

```
      app.ActiveSheet.usedRange().Select();
```

and reading the values from sheet.

```
    ExcelReference selection = (ExcelReference)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfSelection);
    object selectionContent = selection.GetValue();
```

in the second line above , it is throwing exception.. while it works fine for few of less numbers of row. for example it woks fine . for {(0,0 : 90384,48)  - 184025088} 90384 rows and 48 columns while with another sheet having rows {(0,0 : 147554,48) - 185139200} i.e. 147554 rows ad 48 columns it is throwing error. . any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

This might be a limitation of the Excel-DNA marshaling (and .NET memory allocation for the large resulting array).

I suggest you read the values in blocks of a million cells or so at a time.

Comment: thanks. can you please suggest how . using excel.Range something ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you use `ExcelReference.GetValue()` or `Range.Value`, but you need to break it into chunks - e.g. read a few columns at a time.